# How to make a component ngOnInit() again in another component's function?

Tags: angular, angular10

When a user logs in I want my navBar to initialise again so it will get the user's name and display it on the navBar and remove the register and login links.

Here is my navBar Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

@Component({
  selector: 'navigation',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: [],
})
export class NavComponent {
  token;
  decoded;

  ngOnInit() {
    try {
      this.token = localStorage.getItem('token');
      this.decoded = jwt_decode(this.token);
    } catch (ex) {}
  }
}
```

and here is my onSubmit() function in my login component:

```
  onSubmit() {
    this.WebService.login(this.loginForm.value);
    this.toastr.success('Logged In');
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
```

This navigates the user back to the homepage but the navBar doesn't update and display the user's name and new links unless I refresh the page.

I tried using window.location.reload() in my home page component and my navBar component but in very instance that me app infinitely reload and become unusable.

To summarise, when the user is navigated back to the homepage after logging I would like my navBar to initalise again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to re-initialize your NavBar. What you need, is a singleton service, which tells whether the user is logged in, and their details (e.g. the name) to display in the NavBar. Once login is successful, this singleton service would provide the logged-in status.

You then inject that service into your NavBar, and use the properties of the service to bind to the template of the NavBar to conditionally show either Login or User Details.

In your service, you would make use of observables (specifically `Subject` or `BehaviourSubject` to "stream" the logged in events, so that the template can update itself based on that observable (using the `async` pipe).

This is a broad description of what you would have to do, each of the points you would have to research and implement. But this is the proper way to implement this in Angular.